# the most accurate way to calucate date periods using the date object

Tags: php, datetime

i am working on an access site, paying members will get exactly **3 months access period** to the site. the issue therefore is how to calculate an exact 3 month date period.

i.e, some months are 28 days, others are 31 days; normal years is 365 but lunar year is
354 days.

i was thinking of converting the date to a **UNIX timestamps** and then calculating 3 months in seconds. But i am not sure whether this is the most efficient and accurate way to do it.

below is my proposal , i would really appreciate some advice on it;

**timestamp when the clocks starts**

```
$UNIXtimeStampNow   =   new \DateTime("now"))->format('U')
```

**calculating 3 months from date:**

```
  $numberDaysInMonth  = 30.41 = 365/ 12   //number of days in months

  $numberSecondsInDay  = 86400; //number seconds in a day

 $secondsIn3Months  = ($numberDaysInMonth * $numberSecondsInDay) * 3  //number seconds in 3 months

    new \DateTime("$secondsIn3Months"); //convert back to date object
```

like i said, this is the best i came up with, but i suspect that its not accurate.

would really appropriate some advice

Comment: It isn't the most efficient way, the most efficient is to use DateTime methods like add() with a DateInterval, especially as you're making the big assumption that there are 86400 seconds in every day

Comment: `lunar year is 354 days` how it's connected to your task?

Comment: why not add a relative date

Comment: You can add 3 months to current unix timestamp easily by doing `$three_months_from_now = strtotime("+3 month");`. You can verify it like this: `echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s a', strtotime("+3 month"));`

Comment: add 3 months to the current time stamp using strtotime() function...

Comment: hi Ghost. i dont know what u mean by a relative date

Comment: You say "exact". What do you expect to get if you add 3 months to 30th November?

Comment: @PaulKendal check out mark's answer, simple and effective, and yes you don't have to worry if its 30 days, 31, 28, etc. `DateTime` class can even handle leap years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, just use the DateTime object's `add()` method with a DateInterval

```
$d = new \DateTime("now");
$d->add(new \DateInterval('P3M'));
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: hi mark. that looks great; but just quick question. what is 'P3M'i presume that its 3 months, but i have not seen this format before. where do u get those abbrivations from, also is this calulation accurate when some months have 28 days, 31 days and 30 days.

Comment: If you read the PHP docs for the [DateInterval constructor](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) you'll get an explanation of `P3M`, which is based on the [ISO 8601 specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) for time duration

Comment: And yes, DateTime handles the varying number of days in each month for you insofar as it can... potential issue would be if your start date was 30th November, when you don't say what you expect as a result of adding 3 months to that date

Comment: brilliant Mark. great . this is the exact answer i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment into answer...

You can use the php built-in function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to achieve this. This function `Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp`.

So, if you are already working with unix timestamps, you can do this to get 3 months from now, represented in unix timestamp:

```
$three_months_from_now = strtotime("+3 month");
```

If you were to output the value, it would look something like this:

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s a', strtotime("+3 month"));
// outputs: 10/01/2015 11:32:42 am
```

Note, this is significantly different, if you doing the calculations yourself manually; i.e.

```
<?php

$now = time();
$one_hour = 3600; // seconds
$one_day = $one_hour * 24;
$one_month = 30 * $one_day;
$three_months = 3 * $one_month;

echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s a', $now + $three_months);

// outputs: 08/01/2015 10:34:24 am

?>
```

Comment: hi Ltheesan. thank you so much for your quick responce. my question though is, how will strtotime diffrientsate between months that have 28 days, 31 days and 30 days. will the strtotime("+3 month") be accurate each time.Also, i dont need to work in timestamp. i can work in a date object

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime class`  of php 5 is pretty stable and brings accurate results when used 
accordingly . When using the DateTime class it is recommended that you always set the TimeZone
for Time difference accuracy purposes.

```
//the string parameter, "now" gets us time stamp of current time 
/*We are setting our TimeZone by using  DateTime class
Constructor*/
$first = new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

// 3 months from now and again setting the TimeZone
$second = new DateTime("+ 3 months",new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$diff = $second->diff($first);

echo "The two dates have $diff->m months and $diff->days days between them."; 

output: The two dates have 3 months and 92 days between them.
```